How to measure the vibration of an object on a video shot at high speed camere?
I have a video fragment which I split into frames (pictures). I use them in pairs (1 frame with 2, 2 with 3, etc.) to find shifts on x and y axes (i.e. how much I need to shift 1 frame to make it like 2). And based on these values I want to calculate the vibration (in hertz) of the object from the video. How can I connect these ideas? And if there is another approach to calculate the vibration of an object with video, what is it? Thanks!

Hello and welcome to Physics SE. This is a very interesting question but I believe it may be better suited to the Signal Processing SE (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), as people there are dealing with various methods and techniques to process data to extract information.

thank you for the advice! but if anyone else knows what approach to take from those who found my question here - I would be grateful to know.

Whatever method you use, it can only possibly give an accurate result if the vibration frequency is significantly less than the frames per second rate of your video. Otherwise you will see aliasing due to the stroboscopic effect or "wagon-wheel effect" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscopic_effect.

@gandalf61 Yeah, for that reason I want to figure out how to implement this with high-speed cameras (which have several thousand fps on average).

Just to be clear, are you asking how you can personally inspect a video clip of a vibrating object? or are you asking for an image processing algorithm that can automatically identify the vibrating object and calculate its vibration rate?

@Ohm'sLawman I'm trying to implement this algorithm myself. My part is that with ready frames (cleaned from all noise) I could determine their vibration (so the object is already selected and I am given frames with it). And I need to figure out how to do it, I started the approach with finding the frame-by-frame displacement.

In this article https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4264344  describes very similar, but in some places is not very realizable in life, and most importantly, the information with the direct finding of vibrations is small. But any information that can be useful in the context of vibrodiagnostics, and specifically my question will be very useful.
